# What is the most "trapezoid" like function?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a "trapezoid-like" curve function to graph.

The goal is to find a function where the floor of any whole number $x$ follows a certain pattern:

For $n$, linear $y=x$ for $0$ through $n$, then $n$ for $n$ through $2n$, then $y = -x+2n+1$ from $2n + 1$ through $3n$. Values greater than $x = 3n$ aren't really important.

I've been trying with sine functions, which is close at low values to what I want, but then curvature is too severe pretty quickly and I can't figure out how to control it better... but the answer may lie here somewhere.

$$(n+1/2)sin(\frac{\pi x}{3n+1})$$

Which works through $n = 3$ before the upper curve starts cutting below $y = n$ at $x=n$. The difficulty seems to be specifically in "clearing" that $x=n$ point without exceeding $n+1$ around $3n/2$.

I've tried with different exponential functions as well, but I don't have a great wealth of knowledge in this area either.

My goal is something that's stable to at least $n = 20$, and ideally closer to $n = 100$.

---

[Graph of the closest I've come:](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gx1dzw1sv8)
[image: trapezoid function attempt]

Comment: Is the straightforward piecewise linear function not an option?

Comment: @Dan umm... I'm actually not sure? Would that really just be three separate equations and a conditional? (coming from a programming background, trying to find a way to do this without the programming part)

Comment: How about some transformation of $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}(1-|x|-|x-1|)$? Above the $x$-axis, it's identically a trapezoid. [Here's a Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1la12c6sz7).

Comment: If you take @Graviton's function $f(x)$ and then define your trapezoid function as $T(x)=nf\left(\frac{x}{n}-1\right)$ I think you will find that that is exactly what you are asking for.